# How to pass model as a Parameter in Repository method at controller?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository

So my problem is like that, When I am trying to pass the model in repository method on controller I getting error like this ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

Please help me to solve my issue. Thankyou

Please click on the image right below for your refer.
[Please Refer this picture to understand my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZHQx.png)

```
 public UserController()
    {
    }

    public IUser _userObj;

    public UserController(IUser userObj)
    {
        _userObj = userObj;
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddUser(UserModel model)
    {
        bool isError = true;
        var message = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var res = await _userObj.AddUser(model);
                isError = false;
                if (res > 0)
                {
                    message = "Sucess";
                    isError = false;
                }
            }
            return Json(new 
            {
                IsError = isError,
                Message = message
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                IsError = isError
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IoC container like Autofac, register your controller and set your dependency resolver. Check this link  https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependency injection for your Interface in Startup.cs file.

In Startup.cs file inside ConfigureService method add

```
services.AddScoped<IUser, User>();
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, I`m trying to add the above code as per your request in Startup file but it giving me an error.